# argparse: How to separate unknown(and optional) args when subparsers are present.(subparsers are also optional)

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False, add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--conf', nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', nargs='?', const='generic')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action="store_true")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparsers.required = False
parser_start = subparsers.add_parser('start')
group1 = parser_start.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group1.add_argument('--quiet', action="store_true")
group1.add_argument('-V', '--verbose', nargs="*")

# parser_console = subparsers.add_parser('console')

print(argv)
parsed_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
```

Now, when I pass `argv` as `argv = ['abc', 'def']` or `argv = ['abc']`

I get

```
['abc', 'def']
usage: lbrynet [--conf CONF] [-h [HELP]] [-v] {start} ...
lbrynet: error: invalid choice: 'abc' (choose from 'start')
```

What I was expecting was to get `['abc', 'def']` in the tuple for unknown args.
I've checked a lot of stackoverflow answers(such as [ans 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746494/argparse-optional-positional-argument-and-subparsers-arguments), [ans 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049428/how-do-i-make-an-argparse-argument-optional-when-using-subparsers), [ans 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments?rq=1), [ans 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521612/argparse-optional-subparser-for-version)) and bug reports(e.g. [br 1](https://bugs.python.org/issue9253)) and a *lot* but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Is this an unsolved bug? Am I wrong in expecting that this can be done. If this can't be done are there any workarounds to doing this?

Also to clarify, the `['abc', 'def']` got from the tuple have to be passed to some other function to be processed.

Happy to provide any further clarifications and/or clear any ambiguities.

Comment: To the main parser, `subparsers` is just a `positional` argument (with a special `action` parameter).  Since you don't have any other positional defined, the first non-flag string is allocated to `subparsers`, where it fails the `choices` test.  `argparse` allocates strings to positionals, and then tests for validity, not the other way arround.

Comment: Another way to put it - just because `subparsers` is not-required, doesn't mean that is a flagged (`optional`) argument.  It just means it won't complain if you don't provide a string (in the `positional` argument sense).

Comment: `['start','abc', 'def']` should put the 2 strings in the `extras`.  That's because the 'start' parser is called, but doesn't use the extra strings, and passes them back to the main.

Comment: Is there a way to not have to provide `['start']` and still get the extra arguments. Supposing my main command to "call" the program is `X`. That means I would run the program as `X abc def`

Comment: Also I did have the look at the code of argparse where I saw that `abc, def` are first marked as postionals( by pattern "AA") and then that is parsed by `start` subparser. But shouldn't it be that since neither of `abc` and `def` match the subcommand `start`, it should not even go in that `start` subcommand "space"??

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment, subparsers is a positional argument.

To illustrate with a plain positional:

```
In [307]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [308]: a1 = parser.add_argument('foo')

In [309]: parser.parse_known_args(['one','two'])
Out[309]: (Namespace(foo='one'), ['two'])
```

'one' is allocated to the first positional.  Now give `foo` choices:

```
In [310]: a1.choices = ['bar','test']
In [311]: parser.parse_known_args(['one','two'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] {bar,test}
ipython3: error: argument foo: invalid choice: 'one' (choose from 'bar', 'test')
```

It is still trying to allocate the first string to `foo`.  Since it doesn't match `choices`, it raises an error.

```
In [312]: parser.parse_known_args(['bar','one','two'])
Out[312]: (Namespace(foo='bar'), ['one', 'two'])
```

Strings are assigned to positionals based on position, not on value.  Any value checking, such as with type or choices is done after assignment.

Change the `choices` to a `type` test:

```
In [313]: a1.choices = None
In [314]: a1.type = int
In [315]: parser.parse_known_args(['bar','one','two'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] foo
ipython3: error: argument foo: invalid int value: 'bar'

In [316]: parser.parse_known_args(['12','one','two'])
Out[316]: (Namespace(foo=12), ['one', 'two'])
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to convey. That was helpful.

Is there a way to achieve the functionality I desire?(doesn't need to be based on subparsers)
The functionality would be as follows
`X --version` -> gets the version
`X start --quiet` -> starts a daemon in quiet mode
`X get media1` -> sends the command `get media1` to further processing
And I cannot compute before hand what the dev is going to enter in place of `get` so `get` and `media1` will be "collected" somewhere and then sent for further "in-house" processing.