# argparse and custom Actions - code path not obvious

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to digest text commands rather than trying to roll my own custom parser, but the code path is not obvious. Consider the following:

```
import argparse

##class ReadAction(argparse.Action):
##    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
##        if nargs is not None:
##            raise ValueError("nargs not allowed")
##        super(ReadAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)
##    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings=None):
##        print("Read a file")
##        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

class ExitAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        if nargs is not None:
            raise ValueError("nargs not allowed")
        super(ExitAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings=None):
        print("Exiting the program")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

def setup_parser(parser):
##    parser.add_argument('read', help='Reads in a file', action=ReadAction)
    parser.add_argument('exit', help='Exit command', action=ExitAction)

def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    setup_parser(parser)
    while True:
        raw_input = input("Command >>>").split(' ')
        args = parser.parse_args(raw_input)
        print(args)
    print('Good bye')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

If I run it as is, I get the expected output:

```
Command >>>exit
Exiting the program
Namespace(exit='exit')
```

But if I take out the comments and run again, I get this unexpected behavior:

```
Command >>>exit
Read a file
usage: prog.py [-h] read exit
prog.py: error: the following arguments are required: exit
```

Does anyone understand the code path through this? It's like the __call__ method isn't being called (ironic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both arguments `read` and `exit` expect one string.

Parsing the first string results in the `ReadAction.__call__` being called, setting a value in the `args` Namespace.  If you provide only one string, the parser raises the error because the `exit` argument has not been supplied.  If you'd provided two strings, the 2nd string would be given to the `ExitAction.__call__`.

If the parser finishes without an error, your code continues with the `while` loop, without any exit.  The only way out of that loop is for the parser to raise an error.

With this error, the parser prints usage and the message, and then calls `sys.exit(2)`.  A `-h` command will cause the `-h` action to be called.  That prints the help and also calls `sys.exit(2)`.

While `argparse` can be used to parse `input` strings, it's not designed for that task.  Normally it parses `sys.argv[1:]`.  That said, `ipython` `magic` commands often use `argparse` to parse parameters, behaving much like sys shell commands.

`argparse` does not allocate positional arguments based on value - it allocates them strictly on position.  If you define both `read` and `exit`, then the first string goes to `read` regardless of its value, and second to `exit`.  (See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605878/901925)

Flagged (`optionals`) are allocated based on value.  But to use those you have to give commands like

> > > --read foo --exit bar

Comment: I may come back around and investigate using the optional arguments and see if that suits my purposes, but time is short, so I have to build my own simple parser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't binding commands to the literal strings `read` and `exit`; that's not how `argparse` works. Instead, you are defining a parser that takes two arbitrary words, and binds the first to `read` and the second to `exit`. Your commented code would exit no matter what *single* word you typed, not just `exit`. Without the comments, the parser expects two words, and raises an error when you only provide one.

If you are going to (ab)use `argparse` in this fashion, I suggest you read up on subcommands in the documentation.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. May be best to build my for what I want to do in the limited time I have. Thanks!